# Какой параметр передает addEventListener в функцию?

Tags: javascript

```
// нажатие в пустом месте вне модального окна
parent.addEventListener("click", disappearParent)
function disappearParent(param) {
  if (param.target.className == "modal-parent") {
    parent.style.display = "none";
    section.style.filter = "blur(0px)"
  }
}
```

Не понимаю как работает пример этого кода. Что передается в аргумент param и кто туда что-то передает?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback

Answer (score 0):

`addEventListener` регистрирует функцию `disappearParent` на обработку события "click".

Когда событие происходит `disappearParent` вызывается, и ей передается объект-событие click-а.

Читабельней было бы написать `function disappearParent(event) {`

---

Например, операционная система работает с устройством "мышь" и сообщает браузеру, что над его окном водили мышью и нажимали кнопки (события). В браузере реализован "цикл событий" -- он последовательно их обратывает -- вызывает зарегистрированные обработчики.